# When git repository file size exceeds the limit, push are rejected

Tags: git, github

I have repoA.  And I am pulling from repoA and starting a new repoB.
When I started pushing to repoB with the following command:

git remote add newName git@xyz.com:username/foo.git // this is bare

git push -u newName master

```
Counting objects: 6378, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5974/5974), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6378/6378), 126.55 MiB | 5.11 MiB/s, done.
Total 6378 (delta 3030), reused 2533 (delta 388)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: File seqana/testdnaqualstore.dqc is 108.42 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of                                                               100.00 MB
```

Even I have removed the large file from repoA,
the push to repoB is still getting exactly the same error message.
I have tried all the posted method of solving this problem. All 
still not working.  This is a test file that does not have to be 
in the repository.  I can completely removed it from repoA.
I wonder anyone has come up with a solution to this.

repoA has a larger file size limit.

Comment: after removing it, did you push (on repoA)? seems that the file is still on repoA..

Comment: At the end, my only solution is to start a fresh repository after removing the large file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove file from commit history and retry pushing repo data to new repository.
You may either use "git filter-branch" or "BFG Repo-Cleaner" to completely remove files from history. For more details please follow ["delete file from git history"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository). Hope this will solve your problem.